# creating a bash script to create database and user automatically

Tags: mysql, bash

Hi I am trying to create a bash script, which take username and database name and password as in arguments and create a database.

```
mysql -u xxx -pxxxxxx  << EOF
CREATE DATABASE '$2';
CREATE USER '$2'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$3';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON '$2'.* TO '$2'@'localhost';
EOF
```

I am getting mysql 1064 error while executing this command.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 mysql -u $user -p$pass  << EOF
CREATE DATABASE $2;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $2.* TO $2@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$3';
 EOF
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer here did not work for me (got a number of syntax errors, including the same 1064 error as the OP). Posting this in case it helps someone else:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "mysql root password:"
read rootpass

if [[ $rootpass ]]; then
    # create db
    # create user
    mysql -uroot -p$rootpass <<EOF
CREATE DATABASE \`${1}\`;
CREATE USER $1@localhost IDENTIFIED BY '$1';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON \`${1}\`.* TO \`${1}\`@'localhost';
EOF

fi
```

Seems like some statements required quotes, some escaped, some none at all! :D